# What is the use of `quantity` field in `ps_product` table in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am using prestashop 1.6.1.3 Version. When I checked the `ps_product` table I have seen a field `quantity`. I udpdated the value there directly in the database, but to my surprise I didn't see any reflection in the total quantity available in the front-end. After checking this I found the quantity available is coming from the field `sav_quantity`field in the `ps_stock_available` table.

Please tell me for what is this `quantity` field used?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell that particular field in ps_product table is deprecated and is left in the database for backwards compatibility reasons only. As of version 1.5 product quantity is retrieved via StockAvailable class.